# Show, with proof, that the minimum value of $c$ such that $c^n + 2014$ has all digits less than 5, where $c, n \in \mathbb N$, for all values of $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, decimal-expansion

> Question: Determine, with proof, the minimum value of $c$ such that $c^n + 2014$ has all digits less than 5, where $c, n \in  \mathbb N$ for all possible values of $n$. Note that $\mathbb N$ does not include $0$. In other words, $c,n$ shall not assume the value of $0$ or anything lesser than $1$ in general.

For the first $10$ positive integers, we know that

*In the following lines, any power refers to any positive power $\geqslant 1$*

- $1$ raised to any power always results in $1$, and consequently, the unit digit is also $1$
- $2$ and $8$ raised to any power results in $2$, $4$, $8$, $6$ or $8$ at the unit's place
- $3$ and $7$ raised to any power results in $3$, $9$, $7$ or $1$ at the unit's place
- $4$ raised to any power results in $4$ or $6$ at the unit's place
- $5$ raised to any power results in $5$ at the unit's place
- $6$ raised to any power results in $6$ at the unit's place
- $9$ raised to any power results in $1$ or $9$ at the unit's place

Since we are asked to find the minimum value of $c$, we shall start from 1 and establish certain facts on the way as we progress to greater values of $c$.

The unit digit of whichever value of $c$ we choose should be such that

- it either always ends in $0$ and
- contains no other digit at places other than the unit place which are greater than $3$.

From the above list, we see that none of the single-digit numbers fulfill this requirement. Hence, the immediate smallest positive integer that we have is $10$.

Now, we know $10$ raised to any power always results in $0$ at the unit's digit and the only other digit present in any number $k = 10^n$ is $1$ and even if we add $1$ to any of the digits in $2014$, the condition of having digits $\lt 5$ in the resulting number is maintained. Hence, $10$ is the minimum value of $c$.

This is my proof for the problem stated in the title. Is it correct / self-explanatory / un-assuming ?

Comment: With regards to your first paragraph in italics: It is actually a practice to include your question in the body regardless, so it's good that you've done so!

Comment: @DietrichBurde, we cannot do so, it is said that we have to choose a minimum value of $c$ such that $c^n + 2014$ for any value of $n \in \mathbb N$ has all digits $\lt$ 5

Comment: You had better edit the question, Aritro, so as to make it clear that you want the conclusion to hold for *all* natural $n$, not just for *some* natural $n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson please check once

Comment: Now the question in the title doesn't agree with the question at the start of the body.

Comment: @GerryMyerson rectified.

Comment: I think it can be proved that the only values of $c$ that work are powers of ten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal value for the present problem, as it stays after some edits, is indeed $c=10$. To see this, one has to mention counterexamples of $n$ for the cases of $c$ among $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$, and to show that $c=10$ is indeed a match:
$$
\begin{aligned}
2014 + 1 ^1 &=2015\ , &&\text{ rejects }c=1\ ,\\
2014 + 2 ^1 &=2016\ , &&\text{ rejects }c=2\ ,\\
2014 + 3 ^1 &=2017\ , &&\text{ rejects }c=3\ ,\\
2014 + 4 ^1 &=2018\ , &&\text{ rejects }c=4\ ,\\
2014 + 5 ^1 &=2019\ , &&\text{ rejects }c=5\ ,\\
2014 + 6 ^2 &=2050\ , &&\text{ rejects }c=6\ ,\\
2014 + 7 ^2 &=2063\ , &&\text{ rejects }c=7\ ,\\
2014 + 8 ^2 &=2078\ , &&\text{ rejects }c=8\ ,\\
2014 + 9 ^2 &=2095\ , &&\text{ rejects }c=9\ ,\\[3mm]
&\qquad\text{and for }c=10\\[3mm]
2014 + 10^1 &= 2024\ ,\\
2014 + 10^2 &= 2114\ ,\\
2014 + 10^3 &= 3014\ ,\\
2014 + 10^4 &= 12014\ ,\\
2014 + 10^n &= 2014+10\cdots0=10\cdots2014\ ,\\
\end{aligned}
$$
the last line for all $n\ge 4$, so the value $c=10$ is a solution, and it is the minimal solution.

$\square$

---

The minimal value of $c$ for the "other problem" (...find minimal natural $c\ge 1$ so that there exists $n\ge 1$ with $2014+c^n$ having digits among $0,1,2,3,4$) is $2$, since $1$ is not a solution, and for instance:
$$
\begin{aligned}
2014 + 2^3 &= 2022\ ,\\
2014 + 2^4 &= 2030\ ,\\
2014 + 2^7 &= 2142\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Does this hold true for all values of $n \in \mathbb N$ ? For instance $2^10 = 1024$ and $1024 + 2014 = 3038$ where $8$ is a digit $\gt 5$. Also, $0$ is neither +ve or -ve so we can use it neither for $n$ or for $c$

Comment: Of course not. The OP should make clear which quantification - so either for all $n$ in $\Bbb N$, or there exists $n\in\Bbb N$ - is indeed meant! As it stays, the quesion is unclear, and rather the version "... find minimal $c$, such that there exists an $n\in\Bbb N$ so that..." is understood.

Comment: sorry edited the question

Comment: The question was changed only in the title... And is $0$ also in $\Bbb N$?

Comment: Oh, didn't include that. In high school, we were taught that $\mathbb W - \mathbb N = $ {0}. So I thought that was implicit.

Comment: I have no idea what is $\Bbb W$, this is no standard notation. For "the set" of natural numbers, see the discussion in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number - manuals, books, authors use the notation $\Bbb N$ depending on context and on the needs. Some sources let the zero be in there, other want the other convention. Therefore, please just make it clear in the question, since this matters. If $0$ is allowed, then $2015=2014+c^0$ for all $c\ne 0$... and there is no solution. And the case $0^0$ (for $c=n=0$) leads to troubles...

Comment: $W$ meant the set of whole numbers, which is all integers greater than equal to $0$. And I have updated it clearly now.

Comment: Somebody downvoted this answer - so please show the objection for the community.

Comment: sorry @dan_fulea I didn't get you. I upvoted it, I really don't know who downvoted it.

Comment: @AritroShome Thanks, i appreciate this! However there is somebody downvoting this answer. Publishing an answer, or a comment is a kind of "exposure", however downvoting happens often "tacitly" and *very often* there is no comment on this, although it would help the involved persons to have this feed back - it is either an error in essence or a detail omission or something else. Not commenting - while downvoting - is often leading to fuzzy situations, and i am always addressing this issue....

Comment: Okay so as the person who posted the OP I declare this answer to be perfectly fine and whoever has downvoted this is requested to suggest and edit or a reason for doing so. As a gesture for such, I have marked this answer as accepted.

Comment: Sometimes a user who opines that a question doesn't meet site standards will downvote answers to the question as a way to suggest to the user posting the answer that the question should not have been answered. As the question also has one downvote, maybe this is what has happened here. But also sometimes a user votes a question or answer down by accident – a slip of the mouse, whatever. Anyway, it is seldom fruitful to enquire for the reason(s) for a downvote. They just come with the territory.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your answer is correct, but it can be simplified.

It is easy to verify that $10$ works (assuming that $\mathbb N$ is the *positive* integers - nothing works if $n$ can be $0$).

Now $1$ to $5$ don't work because taking $n=1$ we have a value between $2015$ and $2019$ - the units digit is too big.

Also, $6$ to $9$ don't work, because taking $n=2$ we have a value between $2050$ and $2095$ - the tens digit is too big.

Comment: Ah, yes. I was afraid of verbosity.